# SendInput won't work at high speed

Tags: autohotkey

I have made a shortcut saying "alt j" goes one left with the arrows, like this:

```
!j::SendInput,{LEFT}
```

This works fine, except if I hold down "alt j" for too long. It will work fine most of the time but occasionally dropping small "j"s around the path im going. Say i Wanna go one letter at a time, through this sentence:

"Hello world"

it'll most likely become something like this:

"jHeljjlo jworljd"

Is there a way to put a tiny delay on every keystroke to make it able to keep up? or is this problem related to a default delay which has to be set down maybe?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. If I set the cursor to the end of a long string and keep "alt j" pressed down, the cursor will run through the whole string quickly without writing any "j"'s.

Comment: @Blauhirn I think this problem is only there in heavy programs. When I'm sitting in Visual studio or IntelliJ, I have this bug very much and I don't have it in lightweighted text editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is still an issue for you?
Looks to me like an AutoHotkey bug most likely, or wrongly sent `j`s because your RAM can't handle the heavy programs well enough.

Things I can think of that you could try:

- buy a better computer.
- use [`setBatchLines, 1ms`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetBatchLines.htm), making your script sleep 20ms each milli second and therefore consuming less cpu. This might clear AutoHotkey's mind.
- [`SetKeyDelay, 50`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) might also help.

Sometimes, a pressed down modifier such as `ctrl` or `alt`, slows down windows drastically. This was at least the case under Windows Vista. So you might wanna get rid of the `!` (alt) and stick to the `j` instead: the following script gets activated by `!j` and behaves just like your initial script, but will also keep running once you release ALT, as long as J is pressed down:

```
!j::
sendInput {left}
hotkey, *j, sendLeft, ON
hotkey, *j up, stopSendLeft, ON
return

sendLeft:
send {left}
return

stopSendLeft:
hotkey, *j, sendLeft, OFF
hotkey, *j up, stopSendLeft, OFF
return
```

Still, I don't have high hopes any of this will help you.

Comment: SetKeyDelay, 1 seems to be enough to fix the problem. Thanks for your help :)