# Loop Error in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script push space every 50ms but it only does it every time I press the key.  I want it to loop continuously.  Here is the code:

```
Loop
{
^p::
Send, {Space}
Sleep, 50
return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to start it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, you simply have to put the `loop` **inside** the hotkey execution body:

```
^p::
loop {
    Send, {Space}
    Sleep, 50
}
return
```

Note: It's good programming style to end your hotkeys with `return`, but please know that this return will never be reached! (never-ending loop)

For activating and deactivating the space sending, you might want to use [setTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) like:

```
#persistent
active := false

^p::
    if(active)
        setTimer, sendSpace, off
    else
        setTimer, sendSpace, 50
    active := !active
return

sendSpace:
    send {space}
return
```

> I don't know why but it's not working. When I press it again nothing happens and it continues pressing space.

Since it's working for me, I guess your cpu/ram is to blame. I'll quote my answer from this question here: [SendInput won't work at high speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462561/sendinput-wont-work-at-high-speed/29947158#29947158) :

Looks to me like an AutoHotkey bug most likely, or wrongly sent `{space}`s because your RAM can't handle the heavy programs well enough.

Things I can think of that you could try:

- buy a better computer.
- use [`setBatchLines, 1ms`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) (in the very beginning of your script), making your script sleep 20ms each millisecond and therefore consuming less cpu. This might clear AutoHotkey's mind.
- [`SetKeyDelay, 50`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) might also help.

Sometimes, a pressed down modifier such as `ctrl` or `alt`, slows down windows drastically. This was at least the case under Windows Vista. So you might wanna get rid of the `^` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) and change this hotkey to a plain `p::` hotkey, for example.

If this is still no option for you, you could try this:

```
#persistent
active := false

^p::
    setTimer, sendSpace, 50
    hotKey, p, stopSendSpace, ON
return

sendSpace:
    send {space}
return

stopSendSpace:
    setTimer, sendSpace, OFF
    hotkey, p, stopSendSpace, OFF
return
```

This will behave like the above (activation by ctrl+p again), but the deactivation happens with <kbd>P</kbd> (no Ctrl), without overriding the default behaviour

Comment: Thanks it worked!  But now I want to know how to stop it with the same key sequence.  Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work??

Comment: what exactly? I encounter no problems when I test it

Comment: I'm a complete noob.  Uhh... How are you supposed to end it?  Press CTRL + P again or...?

Comment: Yes just like you start it

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working.  When I press it again nothing happens and it continues pressing space.

Comment: updated the post.. please tell me if one of these ways helps

Comment: Thank you... Finally, the one where you press p to turn it off worked!